# Jquery mobile load local html page

Tags: jquery, html, web-applications, mobile, jquery-mobile

i would like to do a simple thing with jquery mobile :

i have an offline web application for android (using phonegapp and jquery mobile)

i do a list with a link for my local html files:

```
 <ul data-role="listview"  id="mylist">
            <li><a href="./information.html">Information</a>   </li></ul>
```

When i click on the link my file information.html is not displayed and the displayed generated html page looks like :

```
<div style="min-height: 965px;" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active"
 data-url="[fullpath]/information.html" data-role="page">undefined</div>
```

the content displayed are not from information.html

```
(i have also tried with  <li><a href="#information">Information</a>
```

but the result is the same ...

Have you any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, jQuery Mobile tries to automatically do some fancy stuff. If you don't want it to do that, put `rel="external"` in your link tag. So this might work:

```
<a href="./information.html" rel="external">
```

Comment: Thank you,

it is working, unfortunately, here information.html need to relad all jquery + jquery-mobile and it seems to take a big time ...

i have done the test with a href="#other_page", it is of course performant, but by reloading all the page + jquery + others libs, the performance are very bad :(


I don't know if there is a way to make the loaded page be interpreted by jquery without loading the library in the loaded code ...